# Does Serverspec support expectations or do I have to use should?

Tags: expectations, serverspec

I hear I should be using expectations rather than "should" statements in Serverspec

I have been Googling around for expectations that can be used for file matching but all of the tutorials I see for Serverspec use should rather than expect. Is this because Serverspec hasn't been updated to use expectations?

```ruby
describe file('/etc/yum.conf') do
  it { should be_file }
  it { should be_owned_by 'root' }
  it { should be_grouped_into 'root' }
  it { should be_mode 644 }

  its(:content) { should match /^gpgcheck=1$/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^clean_requirements_on_remove=1$/ }
end
```

So how would I write the test using expectations instead of should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question:

> ... all of the tutorials I see for Serverspec use should rather than expect. Is this because Serverspec hasn't been updated to use expectations?

No, it is mostly because the author of the Serverspec project has a preference for the "should" syntax, and that's why the Serverspec documentation continues to use it. He has explained [here](https://burtlo.github.io/serverspec.github.io/resource_types.html) that:

> I'm using `should` syntax instead of `expect` syntax because I think `should` syntax is more readable than `expect` syntax and I like it.
>
> Using `expect` syntax is recommended way because adding `should` to every object causes failures when used with BasicObject-subclassed proxy objects.
>
> But the one-liner syntax used with the examples in this page doesn't add should to any objects, so this syntax doesn't cause the above problems. That's why I'm using the one-liner should syntax.

Be aware that `should` and `expect` come from the [rspec-expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations) project, and the Serverspec author is correct "should" rather than "expect" is fine the way he is using it.

There is more info on the original motivation for the expect syntax from the Rspec author Myron Marston [here](http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/).

Your second question:

> ... how would I write the test using expectations instead of should?

If you still want to use the `expect` syntax, just replace `should` everywhere with `is_expected.to` everywhere. This works fine:

```ruby
describe file("/etc/passwd") do
  it { is_expected.to be_file }
  its(:content) { is_expected.to match /root/ }
end
```

You can also write it this way:

```ruby
describe "passwd file" do
  it "the passwd file should be a file" do
    expect(file("/etc/passwd")).to be_file }
  end
  it "and it should contain root" do
    expect(file("/etc/passwd").content).to match /root/
  end
end
```

Or even:

```ruby
describe file("/etc/passwd") do
  it { expect(subject).to be_file }
  it { expect(subject.content).to match /root/ }
end
```

See also:

- [should and should_not syntax](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md) (rspec-expectations project).

Comment: If you use something from `rspec-its` though, then it needs to follow the form of `is_expected.to`, like `its(:exit_status) { is_expected.to eql(0) }`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, all the same it can be also written as `expect(subject.exit_status).to eql(0)` etc.

Comment: I have not seen that before and was unable to get that working myself, but if that is true then `rspec-its` is removed as a Serverspec dep, and removing unnecessary deps is high fives all around.

Comment: I wouldn't get too excited, @MattSchuchard, because Rspec-its is a dependency of Serverspec anyway. (I don't know any way to stop it getting installed regardless.) I tested the above here: https://github.com/alexharv074/serverspec-test/blob/master/spec/localhost/sample_spec.rb